Galfenol (FeGa) structure
I am currently engaged with a first principles calculation based project. I was wondering can anyone share .cif file or lattice parameters (primitive lattice vectors/atomic positions) of Galfenol at any concentration (Fe80Ga20 would be ideal)

#(C) 2024 by FIZ Karlsruhe - Leibniz Institute for Information Infrastructure.  All rights reserved.
data_103454-ICSD
_database_code_ICSD 103454
_audit_creation_date 2004-10-01
_audit_update_record 2017-08-01
_chemical_name_common 'Iron gallium (0.8/0.2)'
_chemical_formula_structural '(Fe0.8 Ga0.2)'
_chemical_formula_sum 'Fe0.8 Ga0.2'
_chemical_name_structure_type W
_exptl_crystal_density_diffrn 7.93
_citation_title 'Magneto-optical properties of metallic ferromagnetic materials'
loop_
_citation_id
_citation_journal_full
_citation_year
_citation_journal_volume
_citation_page_first
_citation_page_last
_citation_journal_id_ASTM
primary 'Journal of Magnetism and Magnetic Materials' 1983 38 1 22 JMMMDC
loop_
_citation_author_citation_id
_citation_author_name
primary 'Buschow, K.H.J.'
primary 'Engen, P.G. van'
primary 'Jongebreur, R.'
_cell_length_a 2.907
_cell_length_b 2.907
_cell_length_c 2.907
_cell_angle_alpha 90.
_cell_angle_beta 90.
_cell_angle_gamma 90.
_cell_volume 24.57
_cell_formula_units_Z 2
_space_group_name_H-M_alt 'I m -3 m'
_space_group_IT_number 229
loop_
_space_group_symop_id
_space_group_symop_operation_xyz
1 'z, y, -x'
2 'y, x, -z'
3 'x, z, -y'
4 'z, x, -y'
5 'y, z, -x'
6 'x, y, -z'
7 'z, -y, x'
8 'y, -x, z'
9 'x, -z, y'
10 'z, -x, y'
11 'y, -z, x'
12 'x, -y, z'
13 '-z, y, x'
14 '-y, x, z'
15 '-x, z, y'
16 '-z, x, y'
17 '-y, z, x'
18 '-x, y, z'
19 '-z, -y, -x'
20 '-y, -x, -z'
21 '-x, -z, -y'
22 '-z, -x, -y'
23 '-y, -z, -x'
24 '-x, -y, -z'
25 '-z, -y, x'
26 '-y, -x, z'
27 '-x, -z, y'
28 '-z, -x, y'
29 '-y, -z, x'
30 '-x, -y, z'
31 '-z, y, -x'
32 '-y, x, -z'
33 '-x, z, -y'
34 '-z, x, -y'
35 '-y, z, -x'
36 '-x, y, -z'
37 'z, -y, -x'
38 'y, -x, -z'
39 'x, -z, -y'
40 'z, -x, -y'
41 'y, -z, -x'
42 'x, -y, -z'
43 'z, y, x'
44 'y, x, z'
45 'x, z, y'
46 'z, x, y'
47 'y, z, x'
48 'x, y, z'
49 'z+1/2, y+1/2, -x+1/2'
50 'y+1/2, x+1/2, -z+1/2'
51 'x+1/2, z+1/2, -y+1/2'
52 'z+1/2, x+1/2, -y+1/2'
53 'y+1/2, z+1/2, -x+1/2'
54 'x+1/2, y+1/2, -z+1/2'
55 'z+1/2, -y+1/2, x+1/2'
56 'y+1/2, -x+1/2, z+1/2'
57 'x+1/2, -z+1/2, y+1/2'
58 'z+1/2, -x+1/2, y+1/2'
59 'y+1/2, -z+1/2, x+1/2'
60 'x+1/2, -y+1/2, z+1/2'
61 '-z+1/2, y+1/2, x+1/2'
62 '-y+1/2, x+1/2, z+1/2'
63 '-x+1/2, z+1/2, y+1/2'
64 '-z+1/2, x+1/2, y+1/2'
65 '-y+1/2, z+1/2, x+1/2'
66 '-x+1/2, y+1/2, z+1/2'
67 '-z+1/2, -y+1/2, -x+1/2'
68 '-y+1/2, -x+1/2, -z+1/2'
69 '-x+1/2, -z+1/2, -y+1/2'
70 '-z+1/2, -x+1/2, -y+1/2'
71 '-y+1/2, -z+1/2, -x+1/2'
72 '-x+1/2, -y+1/2, -z+1/2'
73 '-z+1/2, -y+1/2, x+1/2'
74 '-y+1/2, -x+1/2, z+1/2'
75 '-x+1/2, -z+1/2, y+1/2'
76 '-z+1/2, -x+1/2, y+1/2'
77 '-y+1/2, -z+1/2, x+1/2'
78 '-x+1/2, -y+1/2, z+1/2'
79 '-z+1/2, y+1/2, -x+1/2'
80 '-y+1/2, x+1/2, -z+1/2'
81 '-x+1/2, z+1/2, -y+1/2'
82 '-z+1/2, x+1/2, -y+1/2'
83 '-y+1/2, z+1/2, -x+1/2'
84 '-x+1/2, y+1/2, -z+1/2'
85 'z+1/2, -y+1/2, -x+1/2'
86 'y+1/2, -x+1/2, -z+1/2'
87 'x+1/2, -z+1/2, -y+1/2'
88 'z+1/2, -x+1/2, -y+1/2'
89 'y+1/2, -z+1/2, -x+1/2'
90 'x+1/2, -y+1/2, -z+1/2'
91 'z+1/2, y+1/2, x+1/2'
92 'y+1/2, x+1/2, z+1/2'
93 'x+1/2, z+1/2, y+1/2'
94 'z+1/2, x+1/2, y+1/2'
95 'y+1/2, z+1/2, x+1/2'
96 'x+1/2, y+1/2, z+1/2'
loop_
_atom_type_symbol
_atom_type_oxidation_number
Fe0+ 0
Ga0+ 0
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_symmetry_multiplicity
_atom_site_Wyckoff_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
_atom_site_B_iso_or_equiv
_atom_site_occupancy
Fe1 Fe0+ 2 a 0 0 0 . 0.8
Ga1 Ga0+ 2 a 0 0 0 . 0.2
#End of TTdata_103454-ICSD


Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I would like to confirm whether this is a .cif content or something else

Which is bcc Fe with a slightly expanded lattice constant.

@ThejanHasaranga! Yes, It is a CIF.

@Camps Could you please tell how can I implement this code in order to create QE input file for Galfenol

The error-free is using a GUI like BURAI, PWgui or MAESTRO. A rule of this forum, questions in comments are not desired. For a complete/better answer, post a new question.

@ThejanHasaranga Not every school has a subscription to the ICSD database, or SpringerMaterials. A complementary copy (and  of the same model as the one shared by Camps is cod 1524160 of the Crystallography Open Database which holds 51 additional structures of the same publication (via search by keyword "Jongebreur").
